# ASP.NET Ajax geting error with code 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm absolutely new to asp.net and I want to create infinite scrolling using jQuery Ajax and ASP.NET MVC. So here;s what I got so far

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="progress" style="display:none">
    <h4>Loading...</h4>
    <div class="col-md-12 panel panel-default"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageSize = 10;
    var pageIndex = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetData();

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                GetData();
            }
        });
    });

    function GetData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:64949/api/values/delfi',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert("yra");
                //if (data != null) {
                //    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                //        $("#container").append("<h2>" +
                //        data[i].CompanyName + "</h2>");
                //    }
                //    pageIndex++;
                //}
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#progress").show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $("#progress").hide();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                var msg = '';

                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.' + jqXHR.responseText;
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]' + jqXHR.responseText;
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                } else {
                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                }

                alert(msg);
            }
        });
   }
</script>
```

I impemented scroll listener and every time I reach end of page I make new request to my api which simply returns `json` data. Here's what it returns

```
[{"Index":1,"List":{"Img":"http://g1.dcdn.lt/images/pix/jonas-udris-72559208.jpg","Title":"J. Udris. Scenarijai dėl Šilutės balsavimo reikalų","Description":"Policijai pradėjo ikiteisminį tyrimą dėl galimo rinkėjų papirkimo Šilutės rajone partijos „Tvarka ir teisingumas naudai. Ketvirtadienį policija pranešė sulaikiusi septynis asmenis, antradienį jų namuose atliktos kratos. Vienas asmuo suimtas 10 parų."}}]
```

However every time my ajax jumps to error function and jqXHR.status is always 0. I also try to pass url like this url: `localhost:64949/api/values/delfi` and still get the same response. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you open http://localhost:64949/api/values/delfi through browser?

Comment: @ImadYes, I can actually `json` data that is my question is copied from browser window

Answer (score 1):

You should not hardcode the URL.
If you use a Controller, you could go for:

```
url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
```

For linking to your api, you should look at [Attribute Routing](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

A quick fix could be:

```
url: '/api/values/delfi',
```

Edit: @lmad that is indeed no answer to ops question im sorry for that. Status code 0 means the requested url is not reachable, so what i would do is to edit the url with the code above!

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what if I have two seperate projects? One for API and one for the webpage. And my webpage should make request for api. (both projects port numbers are different). Then this answer doesn't work and I get 404

Comment: look up on WCF then..
Or this: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api